# multicolumn combo box in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Database table with two fields MainAccount and MainDescription table have following data MainAccount 10 MainDescription Capital,MainAccount 20 MainDescription Account Receiable,MainAccount 30 MainDescription Account Payable

I have a asp.net page with DropDownList and a text box. I want to get all data in DropDownList here is my code

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
         using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct MainAccount,MainDescription from chart", db.con))
        {
            DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(datatable);

            List<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>();

            foreach (DataRow dr in datatable.Rows)
            {
                string descr = string.Format("{0} | {1}", dr[0].ToString(), dr[1].ToString());
                list.Add(new ListItem(descr));
            }

            list = list.OrderBy(a => a.Text).ToList();
            DropDownList1.DataSource = list;

            DropDownList1.DataBind();

        }
    }
    }
```

this code is working fine to display all MainAccount and Main Description in DropDownList.

This is what I have now:

[image]

And this is the result I'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: here is image 
![enter image description here][1]
and result i want is here

![enter image description this][2]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/e8hli.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BNbTO.png

Comment: I've edited your question to include those images.

Comment: thank u very much mathew haugen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the second picture result , I have tried this with example , see the two images below.

Add a property class

```
public class Columns
{
    // obviously you find meaningful names of the 2 properties

    public string MainAccount { get; set; } 
    public string MainDescription { get; set; }
    public string Concatenate  {get ; set ;}
}
```

then

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
         using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct MainAccount,MainDescription from chart", db.con))
        {
            DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(datatable);

            List<Columns> list = new List<Columns>();

            foreach (DataRow dr in datatable.Rows)
            {
                list.Add(new Columns { MainAccount =dr[0].ToString() ,
                                      MAinDescription =  dr[1].ToString(),
                                      Concatenate = string.Format("{0} | {1}",dr[0].ToString(), dr[1].ToString())});
            }

            list = list.OrderBy(a => a.MainAccount).ToList();
            DropDownList1.DataSource = list;
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "MainDescription";
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Concatenate";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

Then use the on SelectedIndexChanged property of the dropdown and set your text box value.
Example i just run this below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace DropDown
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                List<Columns> list = new List<Columns>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    list.Add(new Columns
                    {
                        MainAccount = "1" + i,
                        MainDescription = "Main Account Desc" + i,
                        Concatenate = string.Format("{0} | {1}", "1" + i, "Main Account Desc" + i)
                    });
                }

                DropDownList1.DataSource = list;
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "MainDescription";
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Concatenate";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Below is the resulting image.

[image]

Second image

[image]

Also i noticed you changed the combobox text to the mainAccount after selection. Just to let you know  you cant just Reset the combobox text to an item that does not exist in the list . However i suggest you use a public array or struct, populate your array onload, then later populate your list from the array. After selection, you can then refresh your dropdown from the array/list as well and reset the datatextfield to your mainAccount column. Then set the selected to a row where the MainDescription column = Textbox text. I hope this helps. Let us know if you need more help achieving this ?

Comment: your code not working combo box show values like this  webform2(return colum2)

Comment: Nuru First I Need both values in dropdownlist like this check this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/e8hli.png

Comment: Nuru First I need both column values in dropdownlist like this please see image http://i.stack.imgur.com/e8hli.png  after select any value then i need this http://i.stack.imgur.com/BNbTO.png

Comment: Sorry was busy and didnt try yesterday. In that case, then see my update.

Comment: Nuru Thank u for your reply after selecting any item in combo box i want to only show mainAccount like 10 not like this 10|Main Account Desc2

Comment: Then i suggest you use a public array list to set and reset you Dropdownlist. Please read my update and let me know if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind MainAccount (i.e. 10,20,30,40) to dropdownlist.
And on selected index change you can display MainDescription.
 like this-

DataRow[] drDesc= dt.Select(filter expression)

Comment: i need both mainaccount and maindescripton on dropdown list for meaning full list

Comment: prajkata First I need both column values in dropdownlist like this please see image i.stack.imgur.com/e8hli.png after select any value then i need this i.stack.imgur.com/BNbTO.png

Comment: on selected index change you can write-  string str1=dropdown.SelectedItem.Text; textboxname.Text = str1.Substring(str1.IndexOf("|"));                                   Just for dispplay purpose you can use this

Answer (score 0):

i think that the best solution may be by creating a class that contains a definition of two variables and set the datasource of the DropDownlist by a list of this class

```
public class DropDownDataSource
{
    public string Text { set; get; }
    public string Value { set; get; }
}
```

then we will modify your code to work with the new way

```
    List<DropDownDataSource> list = new List<DropDownDataSource>();
    foreach (DataRow dr in datatable.Rows)
    {
        var item = new DropDownDataSource
        {
           Text = dr[0].ToString() + " | " + dr[1].ToString(),
           Value = dr[1].ToString()
        };

        list.Add(item);
    }
    DropDownList1.DataSource = list;
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Text";
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Value";
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

and in the SelectedIndexchanged Event of the DropDownList1 we will write this code to bring the value of selected item and bint it in the textbox

```
    protected void DropDownList1_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBoxValue.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    }
```

Comment: your code show folloing error DataBinding: 'PointOfSales.WebForm2+DropDownDataSource' does not contain a property with the name 'Text'.

Comment: Ahmed First I need both column values in dropdownlist like this please see image i.stack.imgur.com/e8hli.png after select any value then i need this i.stack.imgur.com/BNbTO.png

Comment: do you want the text of dropdownlist to be changed with the number only after selection ?